# IIS FTP - unencrypted access even when "Require SSL connections"

Tags: iis, ftp

I have set up the FTP server from IIS in a Windows 10 Pro machine.

Even though I have the following settings, unencrypted access is still possible. I could simply telnet in and submit `USER` and `PASS` commands to log in successfully to run `LIST`.

[image]

How do I force SSL access only?

Comment: Have you also configured ssl on ftp site binding?

Comment: Where would that be done? Under Site Bindings, there is only `ftp` and port number.

Comment: You can do that also using PowerShell nowadays. If you want i can provide you a PowerShell script for that in answers. I always did it using PowerShell i dont remember using the GUI, hahaha.

Answer (score -1):

Powershell script to create a IIS FTP site for SSL only. This creates a new binding by the way.

```
# Install the FTP Server feature
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-FTP-Server -IncludeManagementTools

# Set up FTP site
$ftpSiteName = "MyFTPSite"
$ftpRootPath = "C:\inetpub\ftproot"
$ftpBinding = "0.0.0.0:21"
$sslCertThumbprint = "YourSSLThumbprint" # Replace with your SSL certificate thumbprint

New-WebFtpSite -Name $ftpSiteName -PhysicalPath $ftpRootPath -BindingInformation $ftpBinding -Ssl -SslFlags 0 -CertificateHash $sslCertThumbprint

# Configure FTP authentication (you can adjust this based on your needs)
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.ftpServer/security/authentication" -Value @{
    "anonymousAuthentication" = $false
    "basicAuthentication" = $true
    "windowsAuthentication" = $false
}

# Allow FTP data channel connections
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.ftpServer/firewallSupport/dynamicIpSecurity" -Value @{
    "enableDataChannelPortRange" = $true
    "dataChannelPortRange" = "49100-49150"
}

# Restart IIS to apply changes
Restart-Service W3SVC
```

Comment: Are you very sure `W3SVC` is the right service to restart in the end, not the FTP one? And from when did `windowsAuthentication` an FTP feature? I don't recall FTP protocol was ever changed to include that.

Comment: Yes IIS FTP is part of IIS,so that's the right service. You can also comment it out and restart manually. Windows Authentication is part of IIS, on a global level, so also FTP.

Comment: No. What I actually meant was you were totally wrong on those parts.

Comment: Im not wrong, check the documentation.You can configure IIS to use Windows Authentication for FTP by enabling the "Windows" authentication provider in the FTP authentication settings

Comment: Would you mind pointing out what is exactly "the documentation" you were referring to?

Comment: Yes your right i think iis ftp doesn't support windows authentication. Sorry